# How to traverse through list and remove via index in Python?

Tags: python, list, search, stack

I'm importing a CSV file and searching through each element to match a regular expression. If true, I want to remove the element. But I want to remove the element by the index, not by the value, especially since removing by the index is faster.

```
with open(file, "r", newline="") as fh:
    data = csv.reader(fh)
    s_data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

    regex = re.compile("\D")

    # Search for any non-numeric characters in each index and discard the element, if found.
    for element in s_data:
        if regex.search(element[0]) is not None:
            pop(element) # <-- this is the problem
```

How do I remove the matching element by index?

Answer (score 2):

```
s_data.pop(s_data.index(element))
```

will work if each element in `s_data` is unique. If not, you can do

```
for index, element in enumerate(s_data):
        if regex.search(element[0]) is not None:
            s_data.pop(index)
```

Comment: For even unique values, the second method is what the OP is looking for. `s_data.index(element)` is an *O(n)* linear search to find the index of that value, at which point you might as well just delete by value.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, both are great options, although I'm guessing the second one is faster, even if the elements are unique, yes?

Comment: @user3621633 if you need to remove significant numbers of elements, neither ways can be considered fast. it's faster if you do it pythonic: `s_data = [e for e in s_data if regex.search(e[0]) is None]`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Maybe you can write out the answer, please, to explain what that piece of code does. I don't understand how that line of code will remove elements. Thank you.

Comment: @user3621633 It's called a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk). Essentially they create a new list by performing a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) and [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_higher-order_function) across some input iteratable. Python implements this very efficiently and is much faster than a removal `for` loop, since deleting from a list is *O(n)* and `for` is [in general quite slow](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops).

Answer (score 2):

```
s_data = [e for e in s_data if regex.search(e[0]) is None]
```

is better in terms of efficiency.

from your code, i can tell you want to keep the elements with this criterion:

```
regex.search(e[0]) is None
```

if you remove elements one by one, since removing from a list is `O(n)`, and if you remove for several times, it's really not gonna be fast for large data.

the one i provided is called list comprehension. it's a python way to generate a list. it creates a new list instead of removing elements from the original one. a list comprehension is more likely to be optimized and executed in c level efficiency.

a similar way in functional style, but sightly slower:

```
s_data = filter(lambda e: regex.search(e[0]) is None, s_data)
```

Comment: Very fascinating stuff. I'm new to Python, but not to some other languages. It looks similar to some short-hand code one might see or use in Perl. I appreciate the lesson. Thank you.

Comment: this is actually a list comprehension, not a generator